# WPF - Access a XAML resource in code

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I have a class Called Photo
what i would really like to do is to create in my XAML a resource for example:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:Photo x:Key="photoKey" x:Name="myPhoto" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and then access it from code.

Not with FindResource() function!

I want a class member to be created just like when i create

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" />
```

Thanks for helpers!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access it as `Resources["photoKey"]`, but not by name.

Comment: no way a class member can be created from this XAML code? and why is it? what is the difference between creating it in the Resources or just in XAML code under a grid for example?

Comment: You can assign Resources["xx"] to a variable in constructor and use that. x:Key is the only identifier for a resource, x:Name is ignored.